# Left outer join not working as expected in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am working on oracle database and i want to fetch data from 2 table. so i am using join for that. My tables are as below,

```
CUSTOMER_DTLS_TBL

CUST_ID     CUST_CODE

68          A2157021570

CUSTOMER_MAPPING_TBL

ID      AMOUNT      CUST_ID     CODE            PID 
1       200         68          A2157021570     383
2       800         68          A2157021570     392


// NO RECORD FOUND

SELECT CDT.CUST_ID,CDT.CUST_CODE,CMT.AMOUNT,CMT.PID
FROM CUSTOMER_DTLS_TBL CDT, CUSTOMER_MAPPING_TBL CMT
WHERE CDT.CUST_ID = CMT.CUST_ID(+)
AND CMT.PID = 383;


// 1 RECORD FOUND

SELECT CDT.CUST_ID,CDT.CUST_CODE,CMT.AMOUNT,CMT.PID
FROM CUSTOMER_DTLS_TBL CDT, CUSTOMER_MAPPING_TBL CMT
WHERE CDT.CUST_ID = CMT.CUST_ID(+)
AND CMT.PID = 392;
```

my expected output when i run first query is :

```
68      A2157021570     200     383
```

Comment: Have you tried writing an actual join instead of (+) ?

Comment: Did you try this - `CMT.PID(+) = 383`  . Decide if this column is part of JOIN Clause or FILTER Clause. Its always better to explicitly mention joins and ON conditions.

Comment: Yes i tried it. but it is not working.

Comment: @Manuel I tried your solution but it is not working for me

Comment: data type of culumn is same. may be custid neads trim(). How many record this query is retunring SELECT CDT.CUST_ID,CDT.CUST_CODE,CMT.AMOUNT,CMT.PID
FROM CUSTOMER_DTLS_TBL CDT, CUSTOMER_MAPPING_TBL CMT
WHERE CDT.CUST_ID = CMT.CUST_ID(+)

Comment: first try `select * from CUSTOMER_MAPPING_TBL where pid = 383`. Is it working?

Comment: @Keval Trivedi, both your queries are working for me.

Comment: Is the CUST_ID column perhaps a CHAR or VARCHAR2 ? You could then try joining it trimmed just to shortcut that one of the CMT.CUST_ID doesn't contain a space.  For example : FROM CUSTOMER_DTLS_TBL CDT LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_MAPPING_TBL CMT ON (CDT.CUST_ID = TRIM(CMT.CUST_ID))

Comment: yes now it is works for me.. it is required to trim the cust_id for fetch the data

Comment: Using the sample data provided above I believe I get the expected results.  Take a look for your self with this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18f798/1).  Perhaps you have an error in your data.

Comment: You should use proper `LEFT JOIN` operator and put the condition on cmt.pid into the join clause, not the `where` clause.